# Facebook release mode wrong key hash

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I tried generating a `facebook` release key hash for my app
and i used this command (in MAC OSX)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <my_alias_lowercase>  -keystore /Users/path/to/my/app/release/key" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

It generated a hash key - but it was the wrong one !

Why did it generate a wrong hash key ?

I ended up getting the correct key by showing it in a dialog in the app runtime.

How do I generate the correct key for the future ?

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question:

I pasted the above mentioned command into the terminal. Got a hash key. **Wrong key.**

To fix my immediate problem: I wrote inside the app the facebook "show my hash key" and simply wrote it into my facebook app.

The problem: Why did i get the wrong hash key when i got it from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for generate key hash.

```
    try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "Your.Packet...", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: I did that. As i said in my post this is exactly what i did. What I want to know is, why did i get the wrong key hash, when trying to create it via the command line ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understanding the question correctly.